# Writing python list to .txt file as a string without list formatting

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
tup = ('Oranges','Pears','Apples')

trial_dict = {
        'Oranges' : ['Oranges just happen to be orange\nTest'],
        'Apples' : ['Sometimes green, sometimes red'],
        'Pears': ['Green?'],
}

path = "C:\\Users\\Dean\\Documents\\Work\\Branch_Configs\\Text"

for key,value in trial_dict.items():
    for item in tup:

        if item == key:

            with open(f"{path}\\{item}.txt", "w") as file:
                file.write(f"{value}")
```

I need the text files to be in standard English. For example, the file named 'Orange' will have the contents as below:

```
Oranges just happen to be orange
Test
```

I have only managed to write the value as a string WITH the list formatting as below:

```
['Oranges just happen to be orange\nTest']
```

I did this by replacing `file.write(f"{value}")` with `file.write(f"{str(value)}")`

I am unable to change the format of dictionary.

Any help hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `file.write(value)`?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, this also wrote the value with the formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `file.write(f'{value[0]})`  to get rid of the list format